# How to properly reference an auto generated Cloud Firestore Document id?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, crud

I am currently working on adding the Update functionality to a collection of Service documents located in a Cloud Firestore. However, the functionality is failing as of now.

Error message from the console:

"Failed to update service item with error: No document to update: projects/myservices-ec91e/databases/(default)/documents/services/5231A3BD-63A4-4AA4-A4B3-81364A2DACDF"

This is my data model:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Service: Identifiable {
   @DocumentID var id = UUID().uuidString
   var name: String
   var price: Double
}
```

This is the function implementation on my ObservableObject:

```
// Variables for displaying Service objects
@Published var name = ""
@Published var price: Double = 0

// Properties for error handling
@Published var failedToUpdate = false

@MainActor func updateService(id: DocumentReference) async throws {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // Get the document ID string from the DocumentReference object
    let documentID = id.documentID
    
    // Update the document with the given ID and fields
    try await db.collection("services").document(documentID).updateData([
        "name": name,
        "price": price
    ])
}
```

This is the full view of where the function is being implement:

```
struct EditServiceView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var serviceModel: ServiceModel
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

let service: Service

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Form {
            Section("Name") {
                TextField("", text: $serviceModel.name)
            }
            Section("Price") {
                VStack {
                    Text("$\(String(format: "%.0f", serviceModel.price))")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    Slider(value: $serviceModel.price,
                           in: 0...500, step: 1)
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            // Update button
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Update") {
                    Task {
                        if let serviceID = service.id {
                            let serviceRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("services").document(serviceID)
                            do {
                                // Update the service item in the database
                                try await serviceModel.updateService(id: serviceRef)
                            } catch {
                                print("Failed to update service item with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                
                                // Reset fields anf show alert
                                serviceModel.resetFields()
                                serviceModel.failedToUpdate = true
                            }
                            // Dismiss the view
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .alert("Failed to Update", isPresented: $serviceModel.failedToUpdate) {
                    Button("Ok") { }
                } message: {
                    Text("Unable to update. Please try again later.")
                }
                .disabled(serviceModel.disableSaveButton)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Service")
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, the view is passed into a List with a ForEach:

```
struct ServicesMainView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var serviceModel: ServiceModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(serviceModel.services) { service in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: EditServiceView(service: service),
                    label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(service.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$\(String(format: "%.0f", service.price))")
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Services")
        .task {
            do {
                try await serviceModel.listenForAllServices()
            } catch {
                serviceModel.failedToListenToServices = true
            }
        }
        // Stop listening for data from ("services") collection.
        .onDisappear {
            serviceModel.listener?.remove()
            print("Has stopped listening for data from database.")
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    serviceModel.showingAddView.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add")
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $serviceModel.showingAddView) {
            AddServicesView()
        }
    }
    .alert("Unable to Fetch Data", isPresented: $serviceModel.failedToListenToServices) {
        Button("Ok") { }
    } message: {
        Text("Failed to reach server. Please try again later.")
    }
  }
}
```

Given the error message on the console, it is my belief that I am not referencing the object on the database correctly. The object I tap on DOES exist on the database.

For more clarification: This is how the object on the database is being referenced and where the function is being called:

```
            .toolbar {
            // Update button
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Update") {
                    Task {
                        if let serviceID = service.id {
                            let serviceRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("services").document(serviceID)
                            do {
                                // Update the service item in the database
                                try await serviceModel.updateService(id: serviceRef)
                            } catch {
                                print("Failed to update service item with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                
                                // Reset fields anf show alert
                                serviceModel.resetFields()
                                serviceModel.failedToUpdate = true
                            }
                            // Dismiss the view
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .alert("Failed to Update", isPresented: $serviceModel.failedToUpdate) {
                    Button("Ok") { }
                } message: {
                    Text("Unable to update. Please try again later.")
                }
                .disabled(serviceModel.disableSaveButton)
            }
        }
```

This is how I am creating the Service objects on the DB:

```
    // This function creates a new service document in the "services" collection in Firestore.
func createNewService() async throws {
    // Create an instance of the Firestore database object.
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // Add a new document to the "services" collection with the given name and price values.
    // Use the "await" keyword to wait for the completion of the addDocument method call.
    _ = try await db.collection("services").addDocument(data: [
        "name":  name,     // The name property of the new service.
        "price": price     // The price property of the new service.
    ])
}
```

Another hypothesis of mine is the fact that I am using a UUID string as the id locally for the Service model. The reason I am using a the UUID locally is because the forEach yells at me is I don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use swift’s [Codable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping#what_is_codable_anyway) it’s

> a type alias for the Encodable and Decodable protocols. By conforming a Swift type to this protocol, the compiler will synthesize the code needed to encode/decode an instance of this type from a serialized format, such as JSON.

With codable your struct will become :

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Service: Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
   var name: String
   var price: Double
}
```

Using codable will help you transform your firestore document into strictly typed struct and after implementing this change you also need to update your updateService method as follows:

```
@MainActor func updateService(service: Service) async throws {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let documentID = service.id else {
        throw FirestoreError.invalidDocumentID
    }
    try await db.collection("services").document(documentID).setData(from: service)
}
```

And we will trigger the updateService method just the way you did but now passing the service struct as well:

```
Button("Update") {
    Task {
        do {
            if let serviceID = service.id {
                // Update the service item in the database
                let updatedService = Service(id: serviceID, name: serviceModel.name, price: serviceModel.price)
                try await serviceModel.updateService(service: updatedService)
            }
            // Dismiss the view
            dismiss()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to update service item with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            
            // Reset fields and show alert
            serviceModel.resetFields()
            serviceModel.failedToUpdate = true
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you don’t have to use the UUID package as our document id is handled automatically by firestore id generation.

Although codable is newly added to the firebase docs you can explore [more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping#mapping_to_and_from_simple_types_in_documents_using_codable) and it is also nicely explained by famous firebaser Frank van Puffelen in [youtube  video](https://youtu.be/brHWxhlC7Ec) and in detail [here](https://youtu.be/3-yQeAf3bLE)

Comment: I followed all steps, I ended up having the same issue displaying the list of services. I used this:  @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString, per the longer video you attached and the list displayed just fine. 

Using the approached you laid out, does not update the selected service but, creates a new one. This must be due to the fact that it does not recognize the auto generated if on the database. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @JLico You don't need to put `UUID().uuidString` the id will be automatically generated and will be accumulated in id variable

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things about `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` is that you can have the reference in the model itself

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Service: Identifiable {
    var id: String{
        ref!.documentID //If you get a nil here it is because the reference it missing, aka you haven't gone through Firebase yet
    }
    @DocumentID private var ref: DocumentReference?
    var name: String
    var price: Double
}
```

To avoid the issues with having a `nil` reference it is best to get a new document straight from Firebase when creating.

```
let newService = try await db.collection("services").addDocument(from: Service(name: "", price: 0)).getDocument().data(as: Service.self) //Valid reference
```

Instead of just using something like

```
let newService = Service(name: "", price: 0) //nil reference
```

If this is setup correctly you can add a `save` method to the object

```
struct Service: Identifiable {
    var id: String{
        ref!.documentID //This will cause a crash if you don't use `getDocument` before SwiftUI Views use it.
    }
    @DocumentID private var ref: DocumentReference?
    var name: String
    var price: Double

    func save() throws{
        if let ref = ref{
            try ref.setData(from: self)
        }else{
            print("Error: Must `addDocument` and/or `getDocument()` to get a valid reference")
        }
    }
}
```

Add then call

```
try service.save()
```

Anywhere you want to save.

But to make the whole thing even more efficient when you save you can create if the reference is `nil`

```
struct Service: Identifiable {
    var id: String?{
        ref?.documentID //Will be `nil` until `save` is called.
    }
    @DocumentID private var ref: DocumentReference?
    var name: String
    var price: Double

    mutating func save() throws{
        if let ref = ref{
            try ref.setData(from: self)
        }else{
            self.ref = try Firestore.firestore().collection("services").addDocument(from: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Then your add flow would look something like

```
var new = Service(name: "", price: 0) //nil reference
try new.save() //add the reference
serviceModel.services.append(new) //then add to your array
```

If you want to keep your `updateService` method it would look something like.

```
func updateService(service: Service) throws {
    try service.save()
}
```

Comment: Good day, I am not trying to save data into the DB, I already have a working function for that. I am trying to update an existing file on the DB.

Comment: @JLico it is the same approach, the core of the of you question is about using DocumentReference, you are using UUID which isn’t your true id. If you look at the ids in firebase you’ll see that they don’t have the same format. You have to change your DocumentID  to look like what is in my code.

Comment: I have made the changes you pointed out to the Service struct, I had to import FirebaseFireStore in order to have access reference be of type: DocumentReference. I see that you are saying that a general Save button would be a more streamed line approach. 

If you would not mind, could you please show me how would my UpdateService function and Update button would look like with the new Service data model?

Comment: @JLico you would just call `try service.save()` in that method to update. The `service.id` you have been using isn't a correct approach because the `UUID` doesn't mean anything, it is just a bandaid to an issue that is caused because of a misunderstanding of how the new Firebase wrapper works.

Comment: In your code this line `db.collection("services").document(documentID)` returns a `DocumentReference` you already have it with `@DocumentID private var ref: DocumentReference?` there is no need to create a new one @JLico

Comment: I finally have a working solution. Will be posting solution when I fully understand the code.